# Calling on click function with jQuery after getting data with $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am gettting data from other php file with `$.post` request.

Please check the code first, here, if I click on the click here div with class "getPostData" I will get data from `getData.php` file. Until this file is working nicely.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.getPostData').on('click', function(e){
        var xyz = $(this).closest('.dataFromThisRow').children('.inputBox');

        $.post("getData.php", xyz.children('input[name="abcdxyz"]').serialize(),  function(response) {
            xyz.children('.showDataHere').html(response);
        });

    });

    $('.abcd').on('click', function(e) {
      alert("The text has been changed.");
    });

});//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body>
                    <div class="dataFromThisRow">
                        <div class="inputBox">
                            <input type="text" name="abcdxyz" /><div class="getPostData">click here</div>
                            <div class="showDataHere"></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**But problem start after that**

Here is the PHP file I made (a sample PHP file, currently no error on the original one or sample PHP file):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['abcdxyz'])) {
    $abcxxx = array ('b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k');
    echo '<select name="abcd" class="abcd"><option value="0" selected="selected">Select An Alphabet</option><optgroup label="Constant">';
    foreach($abcxxx as $abcx) { echo '<option value="'.$abcx.'">'.$abcx.'</option>';}
    echo '</select>';
}

?>
```

This php file will give you back a drop down list. What I want to do is, after getting data from the php file and showing select dropdown list, if I select (on("change)) from the list (name="abcd"), the input text (name="abcdxyz") will be disabled.

But here I tried with on change or few other commands with jQuery, but none of them are working (even the on click function which I added here, jut for sample).

Any help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

**As you are creating elements dynamically using html from php.**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

General Syntax

```
$(document).on(event, selector, eventHandler);
```

Ideally you should replace `document` with closest static container.

Example, As you are using `select`I would recommend change event.

```
$('.showDataHere').on('change', '.abcd', eventHandler);
```

Also in your *getData.php*, you need to class instead of name property

```
echo '<select class="abcd">';
```

instead of

```
echo '<select name="abcd">';
```

Comment: and just to add, there should be an element with `class` abcd, and not name

Comment: sorry about the class which is my silly mistake here while i was typing. i have to study on Event Delegation than. Thanks

Comment: hey, working like magic. many many thanks for help. enjoy india vs aussi game if you are watching. :)